# Is there any way to determine if a Flashpoint requires you to fight a Guardian?

Tags: saints-row-iv

In *Saints Row 4*, when clearing Flashpoints, is there any way to determine if you are going to fight a Guardian after clearing the aliens, or is it random?

Comment: I believe it is always the same locations, so you could consult a guide?  It's not exactly a great solution, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the majority of the flashpoints in the game, there is no way of knowing whether a Warden will appear.

According to the Saints Row Wiki:

> All Flashpoints are manned populated by standard Zin soldiers. Some Flashpoints include mandatory Warden battles, such as Burns Hill (north), Brickston (north-east), Yearwood (north), The Grove (east) and Henry Steel Mills (south-west).

So other than those five, Wardens appearance could be random.

Answer (score 0):

When fighting the flashpoints look at the right side of your TV/Computer screen. There should be a percent number. Dont be in such a hurry to finish the flashpoint is you are wondering if a warden will appear. Before killing the last Alien look at the percent, the percent will read 90%.